# Ruby on Rails: Saving many field types with one database entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu

I have an application where the user can create a project that gets submitted into the database.

```
<div class="project_name">
    Project Name:
    <%= f.text_field :project_name,:maxlength => 30 %>
  </div>

<%= label_tag :new_client, "Client:" %><br/>
<%= text_field_tag :new_client, nil, :maxlength => 30%>
Or
<%= f.select( :new_client, Project.all.map {|p| [p.new_client]}.uniq, :prompt => "Select an new_client") %>
</div>
```

Here they have the option to submit text for a new project name, and then have the option to select either an existing client, or enter a new one, which will get stored in the database, and will later be available in the drop down for the next project created.

I am trying to add a third option where they can pick an industry. This time however, the user can pick many industries for the one project. What would be the best way to go about this?

I was thinking having a dropdown with all the most common industries prepopulated in another table, and if the user wants another they can click a button to bring up another drop down. If the industry isn't present, the could enter one in a text field, that would get saved with that project entry, AND saved into the new industry table which would then be available for the next user.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. I am new to rails, so go easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check this videos http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
For this kind of situation i use recordselect gem for selecting existing objects, and then use a jquery template to add the objects to current form. But you have to do some js stuff to do this. 
Instead i think you can also use a simple dropdown with :multiple => true option to select multiple objects. 
The best way to do this is not very simple... but i think you should start with the rails casts complex form examples to figure out what you can do with nested forms.